# How to format the Twitter timestamp in Java?

Tags: java, twitter, timestamp, string-formatting

I got this Twitter timestamp:

```
Sat Sep 20 19:11:19 ICT 2014
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
20-09-2014 19:11
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SimpleDateFormat in Java:

```
    DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
    DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
    inputFormat.setLenient(true);

    Date date = inputFormat.parse("Sat Sep 20 19:11:19 ICT 2014");
    String outputText = outputFormat.format(date);

    System.out.println(outputText);
```

Comment: but I want to do that in Java,

Comment: Updated answer, I'm sorry :-).

Comment: then how can i convert it to (20-09-2014 19:11)?

Comment: Wait a moment, let me setup a project to test :-).

Answer (score 0):

Just use SimpleDateFormat taking your date from twitter as source:

```
String dateFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm").format(dateFromTwitter);
```

Comment: Make sure you collect your Date in the first line of my code, should be something like Date dateFromTwitter = getMyDateFromTwitter();

Answer (score 0):

SimpleDateFormat is Locale dependent, please use an explicit english Locale:

`SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER,Locale.ENGLISH);`

Now the format string works:

```
public static Date getTwitterDate(String date) throws ParseException {

  final String TWITTER="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ yyyy";
  SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat(TWITTER);
  sf.setLenient(true);
  return sf.parse(date);
  }

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
  System.out.println(getTwitterDate("Thu Dec 3 18:26:07 +0000 2010"));          
}
```

Output should be:

```
Fri Dec 03 18:26:07 GMT 2010
```